# Error in download.file(current_file, destfile) : cannot open URL

Tags: r, ftp, timeout

I have a function that downloads .bz2 files, expands them, and writes the data to disk. The function ran in the past, but now gives an error on the second file in the loop: "Error in download.file(current_file, destfile)...cannot open URL" I have changed the order of the requested files and also tested downloading the files with an ftp client. It seems like download.file() is timing out. When I downloaded the files manually there were significant pauses.

```
Here is my code:

# BuildMetFilesMain.R
# Author: John Orr
# This is the top-level R script to build the meteorological forcing files for
# the Clear Creek at Golden VIC model.
#
BuildMetFilesMain <- function(getFiles = TRUE) {
        # Downloads and/or builds the meteorological forcing files for the
        # Clear Creek at Golden VIC model
        if(getFiles == TRUE) {
                # Read the Clear Creek soil.06719505latandlongonly file
                # for lat and long for the desired .bz2 file from Livneh
                # Research Group
                file_with_path <- paste(getwd(), "/parameters/soil.06719505latandlongonly.txt", sep = "")
                conn <- file(file_with_path)
                linn <- readLines(conn)
                # Construct the download path and download the forcing file by 
                # iterating across the lat and long file. For this project the lat is always
                # length 8 and long is always length 10. .BZ2 files to download are located at
                # ftp://gdo-dcp.ucllnl.org/pub/dcp/archive/OBS/livneh2014.1_16deg/ascii/daily/. Directories
                # start with "latitude.<latitude> and the filename is 
                # Meteorology_Livneh_NAmerExt_15Oct2014_<latitude>_<longitude>.bz2.
                for(i in 1:length(linn)){
                #for(i in 1:1){get
                        current_lat_long <- linn[i]
                        current_lat <- substr(current_lat_long, 0, 8)
                        current_long <- substr(current_lat_long, 10,19)
                        # Build the filename for current_lat and current_long
                        current_file <- paste("ftp://gdo-dcp.ucllnl.org/pub/dcp/archive/OBS/livneh2014.1_16deg/ascii/daily/latitude.",
                                        current_lat, "/Meteorology_Livneh_NAmerExt_15Oct2014_", current_lat, "_",
                                        current_long, ".bz2", sep = "")
                        # Build the filename for the tab delimited file
                        destfile <- paste("./forcings/", basename(current_file), sep = "")
                        destfile <- substr(destfile, 0, nchar(destfile) - 4)
                        destfile <- paste(destfile, sep = "")
                        # Retrieve the file for the current_lat and current_long from the Internet
                        download.file(current_file, destfile)
                        # Write the data in tab delimited format in the "forcings" directory
                        data <- read.table(destfile, header = FALSE, sep = "")
                        write.table(data, file = destfile, quote = FALSE, sep = "\t", na = "NA", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
                }
        }
}
```

Output from the RStudio console:

```
> source('~/Documents/ClearCreek/BuildMetFilesMain.R')
> BuildMetFilesMain()
trying URL 'ftp://gdo-dcp.ucllnl.org/pub/dcp/archive/OBS/livneh2014.1_16deg/ascii/daily/latitude.39.59375/Meteorology_Livneh_NAmerExt_15Oct2014_39.59375_-105.65625.bz2'
Content type 'unknown' length 135942 bytes (132 KB)
==================================================
trying URL 'ftp://gdo-dcp.ucllnl.org/pub/dcp/archive/OBS/livneh2014.1_16deg/ascii/daily/latitude.39.59375/Meteorology_Livneh_NAmerExt_15Oct2014_39.59375_-105.59375.bz2'
Error in download.file(current_file, destfile) : 
  cannot open URL 'ftp://gdo-dcp.ucllnl.org/pub/dcp/archive/OBS/livneh2014.1_16deg/ascii/daily/latitude.39.59375/Meteorology_Livneh_NAmerExt_15Oct2014_39.59375_-105.59375.bz2'
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(current_file, destfile) :
  URL 'ftp://gdo-dcp.ucllnl.org/pub/dcp/archive/OBS/livneh2014.1_16deg/ascii/daily/latitude.39.59375/Meteorology_Livneh_NAmerExt_15Oct2014_39.59375_-105.59375.bz2': status was 'Failure when receiving data from the peer'
>
```

Comment: Show the output from your console.

Comment: Put the console output into the question.

Comment: as its own code section.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem on 32 bit Windows 7 so I"m thinking that is related to running on Mac OSX.

Comment: If on windows, check that your savename + filepath does not exceed 260 characters